# Trouble with SetTop in Silverlight WPF app

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am not able to use SetTop property Canvas in Silverlight App. Following is the minimal code to reproduce the problem

```
from System import TimeSpan
from System.Windows import Application, Duration, PropertyPath
from System.Windows.Controls import Canvas, TextBlock
from System.Windows.Media import SolidColorBrush, Colors
from System.Windows.Media.Animation import (
    DoubleAnimation, Storyboard, RepeatBehavior
)

root = Canvas()

root.Children.Clear()
root.Resources.Clear()
#root.Background = SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)

parent = Canvas(Width = 100, Height = 100)
parent.Background = SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
parent.SetTop(root, 0)
parent.SetLeft(root, 0)

parent2 = Canvas(Width = 100, Height = 100)
parent2.Background = SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
parent2.SetTop(root, 100)

root.Children.Add(parent)

Application.Current.RootVisual = root
```

---

The line  "parent2.SetTop(root, 100)" changes the position where parent1 will be displayed.

This behavior is surprising. I am not even adding parent2 as one of the child object still it's affecting the layout.

Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're using SetTop "backwards". SetTop sets the attached property on a child control of the Canvas so doing this:

```
parent2.SetTop(root,100)
```

Sets the Canvas.Top property of **root** to be 100 (not parent2) (so will hence move all of the children of root too). What you should be doing is:

```
root.SetTop(parent, 0)
```

Which will set the Canvas.Top property of parent to be 0.

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop.aspx).

Comment: Many Thanks. It's surprising how such small things can cause major frustration. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries - attached properties can be somewhat confusing :-)